# How to make Array inside For Loop globally accessible in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code-

```
data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]
    for i in range(1,145):
       for j in range(0,35):
         if j%2 == 0:
            x_data = data[i][j]
```

I want access the **x_data** in a different function **def compareCell** for comparison. How can I access the array in the function. Anyone help will be highly appreciated.

Updated-

Actually the following is the case-

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrpCU.png)

Case1, Case2, .... are generated in real time and I need to compare it with the CSV file data as shown in the diagram above.

Thanks!

Comment: You code overwrites the value of `x_data` in every loop iteration. This means `x_data` is not going to be a list.

Comment: Do you actually need ``x_data`` to be global, or is it sufficient to call ``compareCell(x_data)`` inside the loop?

Comment: Take note that ``range`` has a ``step`` parameter. Instead of testing ``if j%2 == 0``, you can directly iterate on ``for j in range(0, 35, 2)`` instead.

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick suggestions. I need the data from ' data[ i ][ j ] ' to be stored as a list in ' x_data '. Actually, I need to compare this 'list1' with another 'list2' (which is also generated from a loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can define `x_data` at the beginning of your code:

```py
x_data = [] # Considering your data is an array

# ... some code (optional)

data = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]
    for i in range(1,145):
       for j in range(0,35):
         if j%2 == 0:
            x_data = data[i][j]

def compareCell(my_data):
    # some code

compareCell(x_data) #for example
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick suggestions. I need the data from ' data[ i ][ j ] ' to be stored as a list in ' x_data '. Actually, I need to compare this 'list1' with another 'list2' (which is also generated from a loop).

Comment: You can name your variables x_data1, x_data2, etc, no ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, because the actual list consist of more than 1000s of rows

Comment: I'm not talking about your values, just the variables names.
Make a loop with your first data, called x_data1, and another loop for your second data, called x_data2

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use `global`, like `global x_data = data[i][j]`, however I would suggest you call your function from inside the loop like mentioned in the comments.